# Listener for Table in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, desktop

I have SсrollPane in which there is a table, I want to when adding items to this Table SсrollPane scroll down. How can I do this?

It is doesn't work, the listener doesn't see changes:

```
table.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        Gdx.app.log("LOG", "table chanched");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in the code of `Table`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Table.java#L205), there are no events being fired when an `Actor` is added to the `Table`.

However, you could implement your own `ChangeEventTable` which does that and use that one instead of the standard table.

```
public class ChangeEventTable extends Table {

    @Override
    public <T extends Actor> Cell<T> add(T actor) {
        Cell<T> cell = super.add(actor);
        fire(new ChangeListener.ChangeEvent());

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have error: "Error:(11, 38) java: name clash: <T>add(T) in com.rstgames.ChangeEventTable and add(com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor) in com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other "
How fix it?